# How to add Slider to top bullet point

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm added the Bootstrap 5 website to slider slider is working well. but I want know how to added slider top right to bullet points and removed the back and previous arrow, dose anyone know how to do that correctly ?

My sample image here, I tried to create like this
[image]

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.carousel-indicators button {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators button.active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/cccccc/ffffff" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 1">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Slide 1</h3>
                        <p>Some sample text.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/cccccc/ffffff" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 2">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Slide 2</h3>
                        <p>Some sample text.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/cccccc/ffffff" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 3">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Slide 3</h3>
                        <p>Some sample text.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>

          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following HTML to remove controls (i.e., previous and next buttons):

```
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
</button>
```

Add the following CSS to move indicators (i.e., dots) to the top right:

```
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  justify-content: end !important;
  margin-right: 10% !important;
  margin-left: 10% !important;
}

.carousel-indicators button {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Also, add the class `pt-4` to the `carousel`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  justify-content: end !important;
  margin-right: 10% !important;
  margin-left: 10% !important;
}

.carousel-indicators button {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide pt-4" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/cccccc/ffffff" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h3>Slide 1</h3>
              <p>Some sample text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/cccccc/ffffff" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h3>Slide 2</h3>
              <p>Some sample text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/cccccc/ffffff" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h3>Slide 3</h3>
              <p>Some sample text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and valuable answer